# How to make simple search engine?

Tags: javascript

guys please help me to create one simple search engine it should be like when user write any word and hit the enter button my webpage will not show him a list of results but its opposite it should open that particular page, a web page that I'll put somehow in the code and define that-
if this keyword is entered open this page.
E.g., if user type's 
A in the search box  and click search then it should open page "/a.html" 
A is a first letter of alphabets.

Just like How http://dictionary.reference.com does (Its Dictionary site) So what it does is when user types a word of which he/she wants the meanings then dictionary.reference.com dont show a list of result, It shows the meaning directly.
Just like that.
Is that can be done with html form and javascript.?
If yes how ?

Comment: They may submit requests to, and retrieve results from, a search engine with JavaScript, but the engine itself is unlikely to *be* JavaScript. Have you made *any* effort? Undertaken *any* research..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you mean this?
http://jsfiddle.net/Sz2bC/2/

```
<script>
function redirect() {
    document.location.href = '/browse/' + document.getElementById('search').value;
    return false;
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="return redirect();">
<input id="search" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Joyce,

Thank you thank you thank you thank you are GREAT helpful man,
love you LOVE U mmmah,
you are real hero.
It really worked well.
Keep helping like this, you really have a true knowledge and very high sense of understanding people.
Have a great day, God bless U,  
Joyce Babu,
You solved my problem.
Thaaaaank you.